# ROS2 ign gazebo and ros_gz_bridge

Tags: ros2, ignition-fortress

I'm implementing PPO RL with Stable Baselines in the Ignition Gazebo Fortress. For this, I want to either automatically reset the position of the robot or the Gazebo world. I don't quite understand how to do this or what exactly I need and where to insert it. Can someone please help me?